# Capture Response Payload in JAX-RS filter

Tags: rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I want to capture and log the response payload in JAX-RS filter. Here is the code snippet of the filter method that I'm using to intercept the response. (FYI - I'm using RestEasy for implementation)

```
@Override
public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext, final ContainerResponseContext         responseContext) throws IOException {
    ...
      final OutputStream out = responseContext.getEntityStream();
       try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
               out.write(baos.toByteArray());
        ....
   }
}
```

However, the ByteArrayOutputStream turns out be empty. Looking at the RestEasy code, it's using DeferredOutputStream, but not sure how it would matter here in pulling the response payload. I have tried writing to byte[] directly, but that doesn't help either. Am I missing anything here ? Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you don't want to write more data to the response you don't need to deal with the OutputStream. Just use the response entity:

```java
@Provider
public class SomeFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    private Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
            ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        LOG.info("response entity: " + responseContext.getEntity());
    }

}
```

The OutputStream is empty at the time the Filter is called because the JAX-RS runtime has not written to it. After your Filter the runtime will choose the correct [MessageBodyWriter](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) which will serialize the entity to the OutputStream.

You could also intercept all MessageBodyWriters with a [WriterInterceptor](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/WriterInterceptor.html). Following example passes a ByteArrayOutputStream to the MessageBodyWriter and restores the original OutputStream afterwards:

```java
@Provider
public class ResponseInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

    private Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResponseInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        OutputStream originalStream = context.getOutputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        context.setOutputStream(baos);
        try {
            context.proceed();
        } finally {
            LOG.info("response body: " + baos.toString("UTF-8"));
            baos.writeTo(originalStream);
            baos.close();
            context.setOutputStream(originalStream);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'll need the OutputStream to log the response payload as String. The use of responseContext.getEntity() is going to return the response entity / Object and if it doesn't implement the toString method that this won't be useful.

Comment: You can use Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to serialise the object.

Comment: Why the "baos.toString("UTF-8")" only works after executing the context.proceed()? If it is called before it, it returns a empty string.

Comment: The method is called `aroundWriteTo`. You can intercept the process of writing to the response. `context.proceed` triggers the writing.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and solved differently, so I leave here my response as well although the question is already marked as correctly answered.

I implemented a `ContainerResponseFilter` and injected `Providers` through which I retrieved the `MessageBodyWriter` for the particular entity of the response and the particular `MediaType`; then I used it to write the entity to an accessible `OutputStream` which I used to log the entity.

This approach allows you to capture the exact payload of the response, not just the entity attached to the `Response`, i.e. if the entity is going to be serialized as JSON, then you will log the JSON, if it is serialized as XML, you will log the XML. If using the `toString()` method of the attached entity is enough, this approach is just a useless computational cost.

Here is the code (the trick is done in the function `CustomResponseLogger.payloadMessage`):

```
@Provider
public class CustomResponseLogger implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomResponseLogger.class);

    @Context private Providers providers;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        String message = new String("Outgoing message").concat(System.lineSeparator());
        if (responseContext.getMediaType() != null) 
            message = message.concat("Content-Type: ").concat(responseContext.getMediaType().toString()).concat(System.lineSeparator());
        message = message.concat("Payload: ").concat(payloadMessage(responseContext)).concat(System.lineSeparator());
        LOGGER.info(message);
    }

    private String payloadMessage(ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        String message = new String();
        if (responseContext.hasEntity()) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();           
            Class<?> entityClass = responseContext.getEntityClass();
            Type entityType = responseContext.getEntityType();
            Annotation[] entityAnnotations = responseContext.getEntityAnnotations();
            MediaType mediaType = responseContext.getMediaType();
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            MessageBodyWriter<Object> bodyWriter = (MessageBodyWriter<Object>) providers.getMessageBodyWriter(entityClass, 
                    entityType, 
                    entityAnnotations, 
                    mediaType); // I retrieve the bodywriter
            bodyWriter.writeTo(responseContext.getEntity(), 
                    entityClass, 
                    entityType, 
                    entityAnnotations, 
                    mediaType, 
                    responseContext.getHeaders(), 
                    baos); // I use the bodywriter to write to an accessible outputStream
            message = message.concat(new String(baos.toByteArray())); // I convert the stream to a String
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!