# Log JSON responses from JAX-RS web services

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, servlet-filters

I have some JAX-RS web services that takes JSON input from clients, and return JSON outputs to clients. I need to log both the input and output JSON messages. I know how to do so for inputs, as shown in code below. This code will grab the exact JSON input that is coming in. How do I do the same for the outputs?

```
public class LogRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = requestContext.getEntityStream();
        // Read the JSON request input from the input stream.
    }
}
```

Comment: use log4j  it's collect all logs both input,output and error also. try this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/logging_with_log4j.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ContainerResponseFilter` to get the exchanged `Entity`. Add the filter to the provider list of the JAX-RS server

```
public class LogResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter  {
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext inContext, ContainerResponseContext outContext) throws IOException{

        Object entity = outContext.getEntity();
        //log entity.toSgring()

        //You can use the output stream to write a custom message
        //OutputStream outputStream = outContext.getEntityStream();
    }
}
```

To just log the payload, looking at this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/25337892/6371459 I see

> The OutputStream is empty at the time the Filter is called because the JAX-RS runtime has not written to it. After your Filter the runtime will choose the correct MessageBodyWriter which will serialize the entity to the OutputStream

So it is needed to add a `WriterInterceptor` to be execuded after MessageBodyWriters write to desired content-type.

In the previous link you have the full code.

Comment: Hi, what is this class JAXRSUtils? It doesn't seems to be part of Jersey.

Comment: My mistake. I had posted a solution adapted to CXF framework. I have updated answer to use the standard JAX-RS `ContainerResponseContext`

Comment: Your answer is not clear. What do I do with the output stream? I want to retrieve the response that goes out to the client. How do I get the data from an output stream?

Comment: You can use `outContext.getEntity()` instead of `outContext.getOutputStream()`. See also the link I have provided to include a WriterInterceptor to log the final message sent

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. I finally got this to work. I used the example from the link that you provided, using the WriterInterceptor.