# How to print the response body in jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have a rest endpoint with GET method to get a JSON data response. When I try to use `System.out.println(responseContext.getEntity().toString())` to see the JSON response. I only got the @7cf5a594.

How can I print the response?

Comment: Take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332103/capture-response-payload-in-jax-rs-filter/25337892#25337892

Comment: Seems that all you need is make the entity readable. You could try `println(ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(responseContext.getEntity()))` or, even better, write a json version: `println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(responseContext.getEntity()))` (or whatever json library you currently use)